# Jquery ,css animation on page load start one animation after another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

there are one main div contains image banner and textbanner as per in the code. right now both image and textbanner are show one by one. after last image and textbanner i want t stop animation but it is again start showing from first image and textbanner. i want to stop animation  after showing to third textbanner and image.after image and textbanner animation done , i want to cover the div  on  right now onload it starts overlapping here is my code:
not perfect. you can refer here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RgeYQL 
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bolierplate banner</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="description" content="bolierplate banner">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body >
    <div class="imagecontainer" id="pot">
        <img src="img/product1.png" class="img1" >
        <img src="img/product2.png" class="img2">
        <img src="img/product3.png" class="img3">

    </div>  
    <div id="mainContent">
    <h2 >SONY</h2>
        <div >
         <img src="img/img1.jpg" class="imagebanner">
         <img src="img/img2.jpg" class="imagebanner">
         <img src="img/img3.jpg" class="imagebanner">
        <div>


        <div class="textbanner">
        <!--  <p class="thenew"></p> -->
            <h2 class="quotes">THE NEW <p class="greet">ERGONIMICS</p> </h2>
            <h2 class="quotes">THE NEW <p class="greet">WORKFLOW</p></h2>
            <h2 class="quotes">THE NEW <p class="greet">VERSATALITY</p></h2>
        <!--    <h2 class="lastquotes">DISCOVER <p class="greet">THE NEW WORLD OF DOCUMENTARIES</p></h2> -->
        <div>
    </div>

     <script src="js/animation.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';

  src:  url('fonts/SSTPro-Light.ttf') format('ttf'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('fonts/SSTPro-Light.woff')  format('woff');  }



html, body, div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, abbr, address, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp, small, strong, sub, sup, var, b, i, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background: transparent; }

body {
  line-height: 1; }

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block; }

nav ul {
  list-style: none; }

blockquote, q {
  quotes: none; }

blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
  content: none; }

a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background: transparent; }


@font-face {}
html {
  box-sizing: border-box; }

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit; }

body {
  font: normal 24px/1.5 Univers;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased; }

#mainContent {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 300px;
  height: 660px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  left: 40%;
  background-color: #DAA520; }
/*  #mainContent div {
position: absolute;*/
    }

h2{margin-left: 10px;

}

.quotes{ font-family: 'MyWebFont';  font-size: 60px;    margin: 2px; display: none;} 
.imagebanner{display: none;}

.greet{ font-family: 'MyWebFont';   font-size: 45px;    margin: 2px; line-height: 5px;}

.imagecontainer {
    position: absolute;
    display: grid;
    top: 10px;
    right: 250px;
}

.img2{margin-top:15px;margin-bottom: 100px;}

#pot{
position:absolute;
animation:linear;
animation-name: run;
animation-duration: 5s;
z-index: 1;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}     

@-webkit-keyframes run {
    0% { right: 0;}
   /* 50%{ right : 50%;}*/
    100%{ right: 41%;}
}
```

JS

```
(function() {

    var img = $(".imagebanner");
    var imgIndex = -1;

    function showNextImage() {
        imgIndex++;
        img.eq(imgIndex % img.length)
            .fadeIn(400)
            .delay(2000)
            .fadeOut(400, showNextImage);

          //   if(img)
          // $(this).stop();
    }

    showNextImage();

})();


(function() {

    var quotes = $(".quotes");
    var quoteIndex = -1;

    function showNextQuote() {
        quoteIndex++;
        quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
            .fadeIn(400)
            .delay(2000)
            .fadeOut(400, showNextQuote);
    }

    showNextQuote();

})();
```

Comment: `each` takes a function as argument...not a number

Comment: i have updated to eq..

Comment: I don't really get what you want to achieve... But I updated your [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/gRBQqL) in order to remove all 404 ressources and replaced the images with some placeholders (with unknown dimensions). Can you re-udate it so it would look more like your project?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't exactly sure of what you are asking, but it seems like this may be close to it. Hope this helps!

```js
var images = $(".imagebanner"),
  quotes = $(".quotes");


// Look up 'jquery queue' for more info
function oneByOne(elements) {
  elements.each(function() {
  
    var self = $(this);
    self.parent().queue(function (n) {
      
     //Do the animations
    self.fadeIn(400) // does nothing b/c opacity is already 1
      .delay(2000)
      .fadeOut(400, n);
    });
    
  });
}


// This will make the 1st img and 1st quote dissappear at the same time (likewise for 2nd img  and 2nd quote, etc.)
oneByOne(images);
oneByOne(quotes);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<div id="mainContent">
  <h1>Images</h1>
  <div>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" class="imagebanner">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" class="imagebanner">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" class="imagebanner">
  <div>


  <div class="textbanner">
    <h1>Quotes</h1>
    <h2 class="quotes">
      Quote 1
    </h2>
    <h2 class="quotes">
      Quote 2
    </h2>
    <h2 class="quotes">
      Quote 3
    </h2>
   </div>
```